# VueJS + Firebase: Matching Keys Between Authenticated User And Users Collection

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

In **VueJS** I want to create a **Firebase** database collection called `users`

This collection should store information about each user that *has been* authenticated.

I want the `id` of *each* authenticated user to be the `id` in this **collection**.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I pull the `uid` property off the object that resolves from calling your auth method of choice, in my case it is `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, then set it on the database using the uid as a ref. I also add to that object what I currently know about the user, such as whatever OAuth gives you, or whatever your form is providing.

An example in ESNext, within an async function, and email/password auth:

```
const {uid} = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

firebase.database().ref(`users/${uid}`).set({
  email,
})
```

Next time they log in, you can pull their user data using their uid.

At least, that's what I'm doing. I'm also new to Firebase.